# If exists takes "forever" when the select statement takes 1 second

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am curious about what I am seeing. This query has run for 20 minutes before I have canceled it.

```
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT
        1
    FROM
        apm.Transactions as rTransactions
        left join
        apm.Transactions as cTransactions on rTransactions.Service_ID = cTransactions.Service_ID and cTransactions.Transaction_Type = 'c'
    WHERE
        rTransactions.processed = 0
        AND rTransactions.Transaction_Type in ('P','R','A')
        AND cTransactions.Transactions_ID IS NULL
    ) select 'Found a match'
```

However if I run just the select part :

```
SELECT
        1
    FROM
        apm.Transactions as rTransactions
        left join
        apm.Transactions as cTransactions on rTransactions.Service_ID = cTransactions.Service_ID and cTransactions.Transaction_Type = 'c'
    WHERE
        rTransactions.processed = 0
        AND rTransactions.Transaction_Type in ('P','R','A')
        AND cTransactions.Transactions_ID IS NULL
```

will complete in 1 second.

This query also takes one second when I change it to min(1):

```
-- IF EXISTS --removed this line b/c @honeybadger pointed out min(1) will alway return a result
IF 1 = 
    (SELECT
        min(1)
    FROM
        apm.Transactions as rTransactions
        left join
        apm.Transactions as cTransactions on rTransactions.Service_ID = cTransactions.Service_ID and cTransactions.Transaction_Type = 'c'
    WHERE
        rTransactions.processed = 0
        AND rTransactions.Transaction_Type in ('P','R','A')
        AND cTransactions.Transactions_ID IS NULL
    ) select 'Found a match'
```

I can tell the execution plan changes but I am not sure why this behavior would occur. Makes me think that the If exists and select 1 is not a safe way to go.
[image]

Comment: What happens if you tack on `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the first query and force a potentially stale plan out?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just to be sure.. you are adding join for same table column in left join as..... "left join capm.Transactions as cTransactions" !!!

Comment: `SELECT MIN(1)` will always result in a record (i.e. will always exist), even without a `from` clause. I imagine sql server is clever enough to realise that and skip the actual query.

Comment: Also, where is apm defined as alias ? Is it table name?

Comment: Note that SQL Server *thinks* the first plan will be cheaper than the second. This suggests the optimizer is thinking itself clever for applying the nested loop, but the second one where the tables are combined through brute force with scans and a hash match actually works out fine. That, in turn, suggests your statistics and/or indexing isn't up to the task -- the question is not if there's a problem with `EXISTS` (there probably isn't) but why the optimizer is using inefficient nested loops.

Comment: @SurjitSD, where do you get the idea `apm` is a table alias? It's much more likely it is simply the schema where the tables are located in.

Comment: I am curious about cTransactions.Transactions_ID IS NULL.  Is that a nullable column or a test for no row.

Comment: @HoneyBadger where do you see its mentioned as "Schema where the tables are located in" ?. Sorry I didnt see it in question and it gave me error on my local sql when I used apm

Comment: @SurjitSD It isn't mentioned, but that's how you refer to tables in sql...When you test, and you don't create schema apm, of course you're gonna get errors.

Comment: @HoneyBadger can you refer me something similar to read as documentation and example. This is certainly something I have never seen

Comment: @SurjitSD, you are hijacking this question with your own question. But [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx) is how we identify objects in sql server.

Comment: @HoneyBadger you are right about the min(1) will return a row. I changed the question but the results are the same.

Comment: @Paparazzi you are right that it is to find when cTransactions does not have a corresponding match

Comment: Then `not exists` is your friend

Comment: @HoneyBadger The `select 1` is purely so I can have an if statement as the query executes very differently with and without the if. I will change the question so it is less confusing.

Answer (score 3):

`NOT EXISTS` will likely perform better

```
  SELECT 1
    FROM apm.Transactions as      rTransactions
    left join apm.Transactions as cTransactions 
      on rTransactions.Service_ID = cTransactions.Service_ID 
     and cTransactions.Transaction_Type = 'c'
   WHERE rTransactions.processed = 0
     AND rTransactions.Transaction_Type in ('P','R','A')
     AND cTransactions.Transactions_ID IS NULL

  SELECT 1
    FROM apm.Transactions as rTransactions
   WHERE rTransactions.processed = 0
     AND rTransactions.Transaction_Type in ('P','R','A')
     AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1   
                        FROM apm.Transactions as cTransactions 
                       WHERE cTransactions.Service_ID = rTransactions.Service_ID   
                         and cTransactions.Transaction_Type = 'c' 
                    )
```

Comment: I am sorry I jumped the gun and marked this as "the" answer. It might be a good thing to keep in mind but this actually did not help at all. I still get much better performance by changing my `If exists` to `if 1 = ` and select `select 1` to `select min(1)` though I at first wanted to do `top(1) 1`  but it had the same issue as `exists`

Comment: @donL This is just strange.  How do the queries in my answer compare?

Comment: The  `not exists` expected execution is better than the first query but I cancelled it after a couple of minutes of running. Them min(1) option described above is about 1 second.

Comment: `min(1)` not only always returns a single row single column result, it also always returns `1`. Again, I think Sal server is smart enough to realize that, and skips executing the pointless query.

Comment: I am not sure that is true `select min(1) where 1 = 2` and `select min(1) from apm.Transactions where Transactions_ID is null` returns null

Comment: @donL odd. That didn't come up when I tested it... I'll test again tomorrow.